# get birthday of user connected with facebook

Tags: php, facebook, symfony

I try to implement data login with facebook in my application php ... I get birthday to my profile (i create application facebook in my profile) but I didn't get a birthday in another profile facebook. when I connect with another profile facebook I didn't get birthday ... how to resolve that, please
I add this in code js but also an error:

```
{scope: 'user_photos,user_videos,email,user_birthday,user_location,user_work_history,user_about_me,user_hometown'}
```

and this in code php :

```
    $response= $fb->get('me?fields=id,name,email,last_name,first_name,gender,locale,address,birthday',$token);
```

Comment: I think it depends if the user allow you to get their birthday information or not.

Comment: read about login review in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review